# Cannot symbolicate native Android Flutter crashes

Tags: flutter, android-ndk, crashlytics, symbolicatecrash, ndk-stack

From the release of my Android Flutter app, I've been struggling with native unsymbolicated crash logs in my Fabric/Firebase Crashlytics dashboard. These are not random crashes and not specific to any OS or Device. Also this is not a startup crash, because most of them have event logs prior to crash.

I have set up the Android app as described here at [flutter_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_crashlytics)

Naturally, I started looking at manually debugging them, but I have trouble doing that as well. I have tried ndk-stack to symbolicate some of them, but fail to do so.

These are the files I have been symbolicating against:

libapp.so
libcrashlytics.so
libflutter.so (downloaded the corresponding engine file as guided at [Flutter Wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Crashes))

Here is one of my unsymbolicated crash:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/ANE-LX1/HWANE:9/HUAWEIANE- 
L21/9.1.0.208C432:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Happend: 'Thu Sep 19 13:21:07 2019
'
SYSVMTYPE: Art
APPVMTYPE: Art
pid: 9913, tid: 10011, name: 1.ui  >>> {app.package.name} <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000271b  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
x4  0000007d8c984af0  x5  0000007d8c984af0  x6  0000007d8c984af0  x7  0000007d8c800041
x8  0000000000000083  x9  49c5e334e5258da2  x10 0000000000000000  x11 fffffffc7ffffbdf
x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000100000  x14 0000000000000002  x15 0000007d8c984ae0
x16 0000007e30b302c0  x17 0000007e30a6ee34  x18 0000000000000001  x19 00000000000026b9
x20 000000000000271b  x21 0000007d83b8f570  x22 0000007da10d6a40  x23 0000000000000030
x24 0000007d83b8f540  x25 0000007d8c985248  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000001
x28 0000000000000045  x29 0000007d8c9850a0
sp  0000007d8c985060  lr  0000007e30a63960  pc  0000007e30a63988
backtrace:
#00 pc 0000000000022988  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
#01 pc 00000000006c7118  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#02 pc 00000000006de11c  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#03 pc 00000000006e1718  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#04 pc 00000000006e01c4  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#05 pc 00000000006e00cc  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#06 pc 00000000006e16a4  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#07 pc 00000000006df6a0  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#08 pc 00000000006e32c4  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#09 pc 00000000000142cc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+932)
#10 pc 0000000000013e8c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
#11 pc 0000000000012278  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+96)
#12 pc 00000000006e33e0  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#13 pc 00000000006df4a0  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#14 pc 00000000006e1d58  /data/app/{app.package.name}-6tbxQtw3lL741rEFivJhTQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x6c0000)
#15 pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
#16 pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Any advice what to try? The things that seem off are the stacktrace rows with my package name in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ndk {
     abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
     }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.